# How can C# Regex capture everything between *| and |*?

Tags: c#, regex

In C#, I need to capture variablename in the phrase *|variablename|*.

I've got this RegEx: `Regex regex = new Regex(@"\*\|(.*)\|\*");`

Online regex testers return "variablename", but in C# code, it returns *|variablename|*, or the string including the star and bar characters. Anyone know why I'm experiencing this return value?

Thanks much!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace RegExTester
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String teststring = "This is a *|variablename|*";
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"\*\|(.*)\|\*");
            Match match = regex.Match(teststring);
            Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}

//Outputs *|variablename|*, instead of variablename
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`match.Value` contains the entire match. This includes the delimiters since you specified them in your regex. When I test your regex and input with [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com), it highlights `*|variablename|*`.

You want to get only the capture group (the stuff in the brackets), so use `match.Groups[1]`:

```
String teststring = "This is a *|variablename|*";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\*\|(.*)\|\*");
Match match = regex.Match(teststring);
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks BoltClock! If I have 
String teststring = "This is a \*|variablename|\* ok my \*|friend|\*";
do I need to use a MatchCollection approach, or will that Group method work?

Comment: You'll need a MatchCollection, yes. That means `MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(teststring)`. You'll still use the `Group` property of *each* match in the collection - just loop through it.

Comment: The above regex actually captures everything between the first \*| and the last |\*, rather than two separate items. What's the best approach for handling this? Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You need to make the capture ungreedy by adding a `?` so your regex becomes `@"\*\|(.*?)\|\*"`.